# Changing video texture in animation

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk

Welcome, I'd like to ask is there a way to change the material texture of the box in the different frame?
I need to animate TV screen for changing the channels. The one thing I think of was moving boxes with movies to front and back, and by that changing the video seen on perspective.But can it be done in material selection? Or somewhere in the set key mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use videos inside a texture by assigning a "multi-frame" bitmap as a map. (Ex: Avi, Mpg, Mpeg, Mov and IFL image sequences as textures)
This tutorial although old show how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDxTeAvK_c4

You might also want to look at potentially using the Multi/sub-object material.
This tutorial explain how to animate 2d texture using the Multi/sub-object material.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcTxUvO4dPU